# flex amfphp with a secure channel

Tags: apache-flex, security, amfphp

I have an application running on flex and php, connected using amfphp, i added a secure channel to services.conf of amfphp

```
<channel-definition class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel" id="my-amfphpSec">
    <endpoint class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint" uri="https://flashservices/gateway.php"/>
</channel-definition>
```

how do i know if flex *is* actually using this secure channel? i tried

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'
```

and

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443
```

from the php side and they are both false ... but if i remove these checks it works fine, what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

note: I'm using wamp, with mod_ssl, and working from localhost

Comment: I'd use a packet sniffer, such as ServiceCapture or the Flash Builder Network Monitor to see what calls are being passed.  If they aren't using the HTTPS connection; then I'd guess your calls are pointed at the wrong destination.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If you're using a secure AMF enpoint, wouldn't it fail if you're using anything BUT https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Fiddler, when the information is encrypted, it shows a padlock icon next to the packet, and if you open the information of the packet you can see its encrypted.

Fiddler can be downloaded from [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp)

Firebug doesn't show that information.

Answer (score 1):

Open the app/swf up with Firefox and Firebug installed :

http://getfirebug.com/  - (it's free)

You'll see the connections and how they're being communicated.